# How to fix Ball class not appearing everytime i click the mouse

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, p5.js

I want to create a new ball everytime i click the mouse, but nothing is appearing. I have a class named Ball in another file. I got it to work by hard coding how many balls i want to appear, but i dont know why this isnt working

**Main:**

```
let balls = [];
let r, g, b;
let xpos, ypos;
let size;
let xlimit, ylimit;
let xlimit2, ylimit2;
let xspeeddir, yspeeddir;

function setup() {

    createCanvas(800, 450);

    xlimit = width - 15;
    ylimit = height - 15;
    xlimit2 = size / 2;
    ylimit2 = size / 2;
}

function mousePressed() {
    r = random(0, 255);
    g = random(0, 255);
    b = random(0, 255);
    xspeeddir = random(-5, 5);
    yspeeddir = random(-5, 5);
    size = random(20, 40);

    let bb = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY, xspeeddir, yspeeddir, size);
    balls.push(bb);
}

function draw() {

    background(255, 238, 112);

    for (let i = 0; i < balls.lenght; i++) {
        balls[i].move();
        balls[i].show(250, 200, 40);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Added the Ball class**

```
class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, xspeed, yspeed, size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.speedx = xspeed;
        this.speedy = yspeed;
    }

    appear(r, g, b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        fill(this.r, this.g, this.b);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    }

    move() {
        if (this.x >= xlimit) {
            this.x = xlimit;
            this.speedx = -(this.speedx)
        }

        if (this.x <= xlimit2) {
            this.x = xlimit2;
            this.speedx = -(this.speedx)
        }

        if (this.y >= ylimit) {
            this.y = ylimit;
            this.speedy = -(this.speedy)
        }

        if (this.y <= ylimit2) {
            this.y = ylimit2;
            this.speedy = -(this.speedy)
        }

        this.x = this.x + this.speedx;
        this.y = this.y + this.speedy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your for-loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < balls.lenght; i++) {
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].show(250, 200, 40);
}
```

You've put `balls.lenght` rather than `balls.length`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].show(250, 200, 40);
}
```

**Post Edit**:

You're calling `balls[i].show(250, 400, 40);` but you don't have a `show()` function in your Ball class.

Comment: Still doesnt work. Should i show the ball class?

Comment: yes, if it doesn't work then it is a problem in your ball class @Stefan122GG

Comment: there. You can see the class @Luke Garringan

Comment: I've updated my answer @Stefan122GG also can you add the previous code to the question also, just for anyone using this post in the future, we don't want to confuse them :)

Comment: Damn im stupid. Thank you. Im a begginer to this, so sorry if it seemed like a stupid problem

Comment: It's not stupid, just keep at it mate! I do stupid things every day as a developer, make mistakes I've made 100 times before, it's just all apart of the learning process :) @Stefan122GG

Comment: I cant, It says "it looks like your post  is mostly code".